# Event Bus Register And Unregister in Application Class

Tags: android, event-bus

Should i register and unregister the event bus in application class? If yes then where should i register and unregister it?

Once Register of event bus is done in application class then should i need to register the event bus in suscriber class?

Is there any problem occurs if i put some methods in Application class as a suscriber methods?

Comment: I think you need to register and unregister event bus specific Activity or Fragment instead of Application class.

Comment: @HareshChhelana  that means i should not use single eventbus instance through out the application?

Comment: Did you get any solution yet?

Answer (score 5):

No one, except you, can tell whether you should or shouldn't register `Application` as a listener on EventBus - it depends on your app's use cases.

If the event is relevant to a specific `Activity`/`Fragment`/`Service` - register them as listeners.

If the event is relevant in the "global" sense (i.e. centralized error handling based on events) - you might register `Application` as listener.

You don't need to unregister `Application` from EventBus in order to prevent memory leaks because:

- their lyfe-cycles are identical (`Application` can be treated as Singleton object)
- there is no `onDestroy()` method in `Application`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Common class which has onStart() and onStop() concrete methods and instance of eventbus now you can Unregister the EventBus instance when not needed by triggering that class.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe in `onStart()` unsubscribe in `onStop()` or any other Android lifecycle component you wish to.

You should be able to have instance of your Event Bus in subscriber class if it implements / extends it or has any instance of it in your class.